# iOS UIImagePickerController for Video URL Only

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using the UIImagePickerController to select a video from the the device's camera roll.  However, I'm not interested in viewing the video at this time; I want to save the URL (in Core Data) so that when the user chooses the name of the video from, for example, a pickerView, the video will load and play at that time.

My understanding (which may be wrong) is the UIImagePickerController makes a compressed copy into the sandbox and provides two different URLS (in the info dictionary).  It is kind of a guess at this point, but what I *think* is:

UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL is the url that points to the original video; and
UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL is the url that points to the copy.

Here are my questions:

a) Is my assumption correct as to what the two URLs point to, and can I count on the ReferenceURL to point to the selected video so long as it is on the device's camera roll?

and

b) Under the circumstances, is there any way to avoid the compression?  From reading on SO, I'm thinking there may not be, but I haven't really seen any posts that really relate exactly to what I'm doing.  The structure of my app is such that there could be a lot of these videos and users will not want to get rid of the original, so there is no point in having both the original and compressed version around.

All I'm interested in is a URL I can use to access the video in the camera roll.  I will also have to get a thumbnail of it to store with the URL, but I think I see how to do that.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the URL to access the video, then you can use `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` this specifies the filesystem URL for the movie (if editing is enabled, this points to the edited/trimmed video).
If you want the original video URL you can se `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` this is the Assets Library URL for the original version of the video. (The truly selected item, without editing). You can, of course, establish `controller.allowsEditing = NO` to avoid user to edit the video, getting in `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` the URL of the original unedited video.

AFAIK there is no compression applied to the recorded/selected video by default, this only happens if you press the Share button and try to send the file over MMS, MobileMe, etc., just make sure you establish `controller.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh` to get highest quality.